# How to convert a libtorch model to ONNX using only C++ (no Python)?

Tags: c++, onnx, libtorch

I have a Libtorch model that I would like to convert to ONNX format, using only C++,
to inference in production in OpenCV, but I haven't found any way to do it, (or to convert it to any model that opencv knew to load).

is it possible?

thank you